# What is the equivalent of unsigned long int in c#?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c, long-integer

I have a C struct that is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct {

    unsigned long int a;

} TEST;
```

I want to create a C# equivalent of this struct?

Any help? What is confusing me is that "unsigned long int" is *at least 32-bit*, what does that mean, it's either 32-bit, 64-bit or 16-bit, right?

Comment: It is dependend upon the platform? Could you replace the `unsigned long int` in C code with `uint64_t` ?

Comment: My platform is 64-bit. And no i cannot replace it, the library is already built.

Comment: Check `sizeof(TEST)`. 4 -> 32-bits, 8 -> 64-bits.

Comment: size of C types doesn't depend on "how many bits your systems are" but rather on OS and compiler convention. For example long on windows 64-bit is 32-bit while on Linux/Unix 64-bit it's 64-bit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want an `uint` or `ulong` depending on what an `int` or `long` *was* on your native C platform:

- C# `uint` is 32 bits
- C# `ulong` is 64 bits

The *at least* and platform dependency is a necessary concern in C because it is actually translated into machine code and C was developed for many architectures with varying *word sizes*. C# on the contrary is defined against a virtual machine (exactly like *Java* or *Javascript*) and thus can abstract the hardware's *word size* in favor of one defined by the language's standard VM (the CLR in C#). Differences between the VM and harware *word size* are taken care of by the VM and hidden to the hosted code.

Comment: My native platform is 64-bit. So, in this case it's ulong, right?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely an `ulong` then :)

Comment: @pid unless OP is on that exotic and barely used platform, Microsoft Windows